# Finding names in a text file (Text A) using a list in another text file (Text B) and assign values next to the names in Text A (Python)

Tags: python, find, assign, names

I am a newbie in Python language and I need your help please.

I have 2 different text files. Let's they are Text_A.txt and Text_B.txt.

Text_A.txt contains a list of names as following (they are tab delineated):

Sequence_1       Sequence_2       Sequence_3     Sequence_4
Sequence_5       Sequence_6       Sequence_7     Sequence_8

and  Text_B.txt contains a list of names as following (sequence names are written in each line):

Sequence_1
Sequence_2
Sequence_3
Sequence_4
Sequence_5
Sequence_6
Sequence_7
Sequence_8
Sequence_9
Sequence_10
Sequence_11

What I would like to do is assign "1" next to the sequence names in Text_B.txt if the names are in Text_A.txt. And assign "0" next to the sequence names in Text_B.txt if the names are not in Text_A.txt.

so... the expected output using the example above is something like below (the names and corresponding values should be written in each line):

Sequence_1;1
Sequence_2;1
Sequence_3;1
Sequence_4;1
Sequence_5;1
Sequence_6;1
Sequence_7;1
Sequence_8;1
Sequence_9;0
Sequence_10;0
Sequence_11;0

I would like the output in .txt format.

How should I do this using Python?

Your help is really needed here as I have more than 3000 and 6000 names in Text_A.txt and Text_B.txt files respectively.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please also give the portion of code you tried to solve this out. That would give others a way to find what's the error in your code that's not working!

Comment: Hi Deca, thank you for your message... I am really a beginner so I don't know where to start....

Comment: 6000 is not a big number, I mean not big enough to create difficulties that basic code and basic hardware can't handle.

Comment: :) I think many would disagree with this approach, as you are expected to go through all the help in google, such as writing basic programs in python, how to write or read from a file, etc. before posting in stackoverflow! People use to post when they are stuck!

Comment: SO is neither a code writing service nor a tutorial website.

Comment: I'm sorry for my wrong approach of asking the question. I was hoping to get a starting point rather than a whole script. I'm very sorry again and next time I will try myself and ask for advice when I get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do the following

```
# read each file assuming that your sequence of strings 
# is the first line respectively
with open('Text_A.txt', 'r') as f:
    seqA = f.readline()
with open('Text_B.txt', 'r') as f:
    seqB = f.readline()

# remove end-of-line character
seqA = seqA.strip('\n')
seqB = seqB.strip('\n')

# so far, seqA and seqB are strings. split them now on tabs
seqA = seqA.split('\t')
seqB = seqB.split('\t')

# now, seqA and seqB are list of strings
# since you want to use seqA as a lookup, you should make a set out of seqA
seqA = set( seqA )

# now iterate over each item in seqB and check if it is present in seqA
# store result in a list
out = []
for item in seqB:
    is_present = 1 if item in seqA else 0
    out.append('{item}:{is_presnet}\n'.format(item=item,is_present=is_present))

# write result to file
with open('output.txt','w') as f:
    f.write( '\t'.join( out ) )
```

If your sequences contain several millions entries you should think about a more advanced approach.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I will go through this carefully and learn.

Comment: Please do not forget to mark those answers which are useful for you and accept the answer which helped you most.